# Multiple PopUp Window

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I am working on a webpage that involves interactive media opening in different popup windows.  I want the focus to go to the newest window when it opens.  I am having trouble keeping all of my pop up windows open at once.  When the next window opens, the previous closes.

Here is the code

First window:

```
<script language="javascript">

function popup(url) {
        var width = 300;
        var height = 300;
        var left = 200;
        var top = 100;
        var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
        params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
        params += ', directories=no';
        params += ', location=no';
        params += ', menubar=no';
        params += ', resizable=no';
        params += ', scrollbars=no';
        params += ', status=no';
        params += ', toolbar=no';
        win1 = window.open(url, "laser", params);
        if (window.focus) {
            win1.focus()
        }

        return false;

    }
    setTimeout(function() {popup('laser.html');}, 10000)
</script>
```

Second Window:

```
<script language="javascript">

function popup(url) {
        var width = 300;
        var height = 300;
        var left = 500;
        var top = 300;
        var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
        params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
        params += ', directories=no';
        params += ', location=no';
        params += ', menubar=no';
        params += ', resizable=no';
        params += ', scrollbars=no';
        params += ', status=no';
        params += ', toolbar=no';
        win2 = window.open(url, "fire", params);
        if (window.focus) {
            win2.focus()
        }

        return false;

    }
    setTimeout(function() {popup('fire.html');}, 13000)
</script>
```

Comment: use jquery diolog it's much easier contains the focus ability

Comment: Same function `popup`? But the window name is hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Sora, my school is making me use java :(

Comment: Also, Abhi, is there anyway around this? something I can change to make this work?